# Rails Wicegrid checkbox filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wice-grid

I'm using wice grid in my application. I have a model which is having a highlight attribute with boolean values. In wice grid table, I do not want to use the default dropdown filter, instead use some checkbox or toggle button.

```
<%= grid(event_grid) do |g|
  g.column name: 'Highlight', attribute: 'highlight' do |event|
    event.highlight
  end
end -%>
```

By default, the filter is dropdown with true and false values. I want to have a checkbox filter instead of dropdown.
Let me know if you need any more details... Thanks

Comment: Wicegrid allows you to define custom filters option. Please follow https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid#defining-your-own-external-filter-processors

Comment: I did go through the documentation but i did not find my answer there. Custom filters are for custom drop down and I do not want drop down filter.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
g.column name: 'Highlight', attribute: 'highlight', auto_reload: true do |event|
    check_box "event", "highlight", {:checked => event.highlight, :disabled => true}
end
```